# Constraining a ListView's width to parent to force child text to wrap

Tags: wpf, layout

I'm trying to get a window similar to a chat window, where a list of text items is drawn. The window should be resizable and each text item should wrap if it does not fit on one line.

What I have so far:

`MessageItem` - A user control, multiline TextBlock in a Border

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,10" Name="messageContainer" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
        <TextBlock Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="messageContent" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Text="This is some longer text. Wow that wasn't as long as I thought." TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="10" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

`MessageBox` - A user control with a ListView that holds MessageItems

```
<Grid Name="messageGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <!--<StackPanel Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="messagePanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">

        </StackPanel> -->
        <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <local:MessageItem></local:MessageItem>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The Problem:

If I use the commented out StackPanel for holding MessageItems, It will shrink the MessageItem (and cause the text to wrap) correctly. If I use the ListView, it does not shrink.

I've more or less figured out why from research, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get around it. As far as I can tell I need to override MeasureOverride and/or ArrangeOverride, but I'm far too new to WPF to know WTF I'm doing. (rimshot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're putting the ListView inside a ScrollViewer since the ListView has its own ScrollView internally.

In order to get your MessageItems to wrap you need to turn off any horizontal scrollbars, otherwise the container (ListView or ScrollViewer) will give the MessageItem as much space as it requires and show a scrollbar.

Try

```
<ScrollViewer ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

and

```
<ListView ... ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

although I'm not sure you even need the ScrollViewer.

You would probably be better off using a ListBox and an ItemTemplate instead of the ListView and user control

Comment: Wow that was way easier than I expected. As for the ScrollViewer: Resize window so the ListView is bigger than the window -> "Hey a scroll bar didn't show up" -> Toolbox -> ScrolViewer -> "That's just what I need!" :)  Like I said I'm new to WPF :P